# Downgrade a new Mac from OSX 10.14 to 10.11?

Tags: macos

Ive got a Macbook Pro which i think is life expired. This Macbook Pro is running OSX 10.11 which is the highest OSX version i can go, as i need to run some specific software which only works on 10.11

Im looking at buying a new Macbook Pro, but presume they will come pre installed with OSX 10.14 is there anyway i can downgrade the new Macbook Pro to 10.11 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of running it a VM, no.

The general rule is no Mac will run an OS older than itself - there can be no drivers for hardware that wasn't yet invented, so Apple make sure that doesn't happen.